# GWT DatePicker defaults to noon

Tags: gwt, datepicker

DatePicker returns a Date you click on.  However, the Date object time is set to noon.  Is there a way to change it from noon to a different time?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of the object in your backing code.

```
Datepicker dp;
//UI does some stuff
Date offset = new Date(somemilliseconds); //replace somemilliseconds with the value you want to roll forward or backwards
dp.setValue(dp.getValue()+offset); //or minus
```

However the DatePicker UI element itself has no time way to pick a time (it is just a calendar) to go with your date, you would have to use a different UI element that could change the object that you set with your DatePicker (if you didn't want to use a calculated offset like the above.)

Comment: I would like to avoid manually changing the returned value.  I am using a DateBox widget.